# How to I invoke a function with the number 9 from this array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

How to I invoke a function with the number 9 from this array?

```
     var puzzlers = [

       function ( a ) { return 8*a - 10; }, 
       function ( a ) { return (a-3) * (a-3) * (a-3); }, 
       function ( a ) { return a * a + 4; },
       function ( a ) { return a % 5; }
     ];
```

is this example correct?

```
    puzzlers[0](9);
```

Comment: Yes. But seriously, you could have run this in console before posting here to see it working exactly as expected

Answer (score 1):

Correct!!

`puzzlers[0]` will be `function ( a ) { return 8*a - 10; }`
then you are invoking `function ( a ) { return 8*a - 10; }` with `9` as `a`.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. It will call first function from the array with parameter 9.

You can open [`this link`](http://jsfiddle.net/9HuBY/) and open the browser console and run the example to see the result.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, however there is an alternative, where you only need one function,
and you can use the java script switch.

```
    function puzzlers(a,b){

      var answer;

      switch(b){

            case 1:
                answer = 8*a - 10;  
                break;
            case 2:
                answer = (a-3) * (a-3) * (a-3); 
                break;
            case 3:
                answer = a * a + 4; 
                break;
            case 4:
               answer = a % 5;  
               break;
            default:
               break;
    }

    return answer;
 }
```

so run the function such as, puzzlers(9,1) will give you 62.